# some opencv functions dont work inside visual studio environment (start debugging) but runs through the .exe file

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013

I've made some opencv(c++) programs and they work fine when I run the .exe files. However, when I try to debug then inside visual studio, some functions just don't work. The window just close even running inside a try-catch statement. And the weird thing is that just some functions crashes the application, for instance, I can load, manipulate and diplay images, but I cant run the camera.
To get even worst, it just happen in my desktop, my laptop works fine. I have tried to reinstall everything (VS and openCV), to unable firewall, anti-virus, etc..

I am using visual studio professional 2013, windows 7 and opencv 2.4.

Comment: apparently you are missing some libraries...try to go to event log and check out the messages related to the crash and print this message in here...

Comment: set debug execution path to your .exe path

Comment: I did.. stil not working. Relating to event log reports, I found no log regarding the problem.